# MENU LATERAL DESLIZANTE

Tags: html, css

Tengo un menu lateral deslizante, pero lo tengo posicionado en la izquierda y se desliza para la derecha, ya se como hacer para posicionarlo en la derecha pero **no se como hacer para que se deslice a la izquierda** (para explicar un poco mejor, el menu se abre a la derecha y requiero que abra a la izquierda).

**Este es mi código**

```css
.sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        background-color: #000000;
        float: right;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.4s;
        padding: 2rem 0;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
        <a href="#" class="boton-cerrar" onclick="ocultar()">&times;</a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Opción 1</li>
        <li><a href="#">Opción 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Opción 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Opción 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Opción 5</a></li>
    </ul>
      
    </div>
```

gracias por su ayuda

Comment: @David081: evita convertir el código a snippet si es que este no es funcional en la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para cambiar de lado el menú, basta usar `right` en ves de `left`.

Pero realice algunos cambios para que funcione: a la transcripción agregué `right`; al menú le puse un ancho fijo de `width: 200px`; y el javascript para el ejemplo.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", e => {  

document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.toggle("activo");  

});
```

```css
.sidebar {
   position: fixed;
   height: 100%;
   width: 200px;
   top: 0;
   right: -100%;
   background-color: #000000;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   transition: right 0.4s;
   padding: 2rem 0;
   box-sizing:border-box;
} 
  
.sidebar.activo {
   right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>Menu</button>

<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
<a href="#" class="boton-cerrar" onclick="ocultar()">&times;</a>
<ul class="menu">
<li>Opción 1</li>
<li><a href="#">Opción 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Opción 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Opción 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Opción 5</a></li>
</ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy amable

Comment: Bien @JhonatanPeláez si esto ayuda, sería tan amable de aceptar la respuesta con el ✓ para que sirva a otros también y quedé cerra tu pregunta